# Simulate Pressing the Enter Key with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, input

I'm trying to simulate the user hitting the enter key when they leave a input field (.blur).
So very basically, on blur, it simulates that the user actually pressed the ENTER key on their keyboard...Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: What is the purpose? Are you just trying to add a newline to the text input?

Comment: Why the enter key, what action would that do?  I'd suggest just doing that action.

Comment: The reason is that I have a field that lets users enter "tags", but sometimes they dont realize that they have to hit Enter or Tab after adding a tag...they just click off the field and it does not create the tag..

Comment: Have you considered triggering the tag feature on blur(), or after some delay?  Or a note telling the user to hit Return?

Answer (score 6):

```
$("input").blur(function() {
    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    e.which = 13; // Enter
    $("input").trigger(e);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KGjKy/)

Comment: No, I definitely want it to happen on blur. I want it to be 'as if' the user hit enter, as soon as they leave the input field

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment

> The reason is that I have a field that lets users enter "tags", but
>   sometimes they dont realize that they have to hit Enter or Tab after
>   adding a tag...they just click off the field and it does not create
>   the tag..

Try,

```
$("input").blur( /* Fx that adds the Tag*/);
```

**Note**: You may need to revise the keydown event handler for tab, because the `.blur` will be triggered when you hit tab.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just trigger whatever action the enter key would perform, such as `$(this).closest('form')[0].submit();` to submit the form containing the field.

Comment: Why do you need `[0]`?  `.closest` should only ever return 1 element.

Comment: Maybe he doesn't have a form and is doing it with an ajax request that then navigates to a returned url. We don't know much about what his code looks like

Comment: The jQuery `.submit()` function will not actually submit the form - at least it used to be like that; so i'm calling the native DOM method.

Comment: The problem is that I'm using an ExpressionEngine module for this seems to do all of this and I'm trying to modify it 'after the fact' without hacking the module